# Render JCombobox to the right problem

Tags: java, swing, orientation, jcombobox, right-to-left

I want to let JComboBox be aligned from right to left and to render text from right to left
I have set component orientation and also change the render as follows:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form NewJFrame */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        jComboBox1.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);        
jComboBox1.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList jList, Object o,
    int i, boolean b, boolean b1) {
    JLabel rendrlbl = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(jList, o, i, b, b1);
    rendrlbl.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    return rendrlbl;
    }
    });


    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jComboBox1.setEditable(true);
        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));

        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .add(55, 55, 55)
                .add(jComboBox1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 268, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(77, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .add(37, 37, 37)
                .add(jComboBox1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(236, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

[image]

As you may have seen in this screenshot the combobox and it's cursor is aligned to the left while the list is aligned to the right. How can I solve this?

Comment: please post runnable code that shows you issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it's cursor is aligned to the left while the list is aligned to the right. How can I solve this?

Sounds like you have an editable combo box. Therefore I guess you also need to change the orientation of the editor component:

```
ComboBoxEditor editor = comboBox.getEditor();
JTextField textField = (JTextField)editor.getEditorComponent();
textField.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

Comment: That's works fine for the editor but what about the orientation of all the component? I mean the right arrow image should be aligned to the left.